# Is it possible to load a template inside a template with jquery-load?

Tags: jquery, html, ionic-framework

I'm working on an Ionic-tabs-app for iPad.
On one of my templates i have on the left side a treeview with items and on the left side an empty div called "panel_dynamic_to_treeitem".
When i click on an item of the tree i want to load another template -  including it's controller - into the empty div.
In other experiments i could load the template but had no relation to the controller.
Unfortunately i cannot use states here (as i do normally to open templates in tabs).
Further in some cases i want to set parameters too.
Can all this be done (relation from template to controller and parameters)?

My first attempt to load a template with jquery Looks like that:

```
    if(item.id == 9999)
    {
        $('#panel_dynamic_to_treeitem').load('templates/type-of-test.html');
    }
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

i think you you are looking for the Model in Ionic.
In Model you can call the template and also bind the controller to that particular template. use this [link](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicModal/) to learn about the model in Ionic.

Comment: Looks useful. It seems that the script-tag is not needed, when the template i want to load is in it's own HTML-file. But is it necessary, that the controller of the template to be loaded is in the controller, which loads the template? Is there a possibility to keep the controllers separated?